# How to make product category column sortable in admin order page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im struggling to make column sortable. now sortable is working but not sorting a to z. Maybe i have added the wrong meta key or something else. i have tried to find meta key for product category in database. However all tries are failed. Please help to get it fix. Thank you

```
dd_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'wcof_xtra_order_columns',11);
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'wcof_xtra_orders_column_content', 10, 2 );

function wcof_xtra_order_columns($columns)
{
   //add columns
    $columns['product-cats'] = __( 'Product categories','wcof');
  
   return $columns;
}

function wcof_xtra_orders_column_content($column)
{
    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;
    
    // Check if the order instance is empty and instantiate it
    if ( empty( $the_order ) || $the_order->get_order_number() != $post->ID )
        $the_order = new WC_Order( $post->ID );
    
    if ($column == "product-cats")
    {

        // the order has at least 1 product
        if (sizeof($the_order->get_items()) > 0){

            $_cats = array();

            foreach( $the_order->get_items() as $item){
                if ($item['product_id'] > 0){
                    
                    if ($item->get_variation_id() > 0){
                        $_product_v = new WC_Product_Variation($item->get_variation_id());
                        $_product = wc_get_product($_product_v->get_parent_id());
                    }else{
                        $_product = $the_order->get_product_from_item($item);
                        
                    }
                    $_cats = array_merge($_cats, $_product->get_category_ids());
                }
            }
        }
    
        foreach($_cats as $key=>$cat_id){
            $_cats[$key] = get_term_by('id', $cat_id, 'product_cat')->name;
        }
        echo implode(",", array_unique($_cats));
    }
    
}
    


add_filter( "manage_edit-shop_order_sortable_columns", 'shop_order_column_meta_field_sortable' );
function shop_order_column_meta_field_sortable( $columns )
{
    $meta_key = '_product_id';
    return wp_parse_args( array('product-cats' => $meta_key), $columns );
}

// Make sorting work properly (by numerical values)
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'shop_order_column_meta_field_sortable_orderby' );
function shop_order_column_meta_field_sortable_orderby( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'shop_order' === $_GET['post_type'] ){

        $orderby  = $query->get( 'orderby');
        $meta_key = '_product_id';

        if ('product-cats' === $orderby){
          $query->set('meta_key', $meta_key);
          $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make this column a-z sortable. Currently it is not sorting correctly.